# How to install Oracle on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, oracle-database

I tried going through [the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Oracle)

I was able to complete until here.

```
wget --http-user "I accept www.opensource.org/licenses/cpl" --http-password "." http://www.research.att.com/~gsf/download/tgz/INIT.2011-02-08.tgz
```

Then, it says that the INIT package is not found. Not sure what to do next.

I tried to go to Oracle and download and proceed anyways by untarring and trying to setup. It is showing many errors.

I was wondering if anybody had successfully installed Oracle on Arch?

**EDIT:**

I tried the following in the above link:

```
[srikanth@myhost Downloads]$ tar -xvf oracle.tar.gz 
oracle
oracle/PKGBUILD
oracle/oracle.install
oracle/ee.rsp.patch
oracle/oracledb
[srikanth@myhost Downloads]$ cd oracle
[srikanth@myhost oracle]$ ls
ee.rsp.patch  oracledb  oracle.install  PKGBUILD
[srikanth@myhost oracle]$ makepkg -s
==> Making package: oracle 11gR1-1 (Thu Jan 19 21:54:20 CST 2012)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Installing missing dependencies...
Password: 
error: target not found: ksh
==> ERROR: 'pacman' failed to install missing dependencies.
```

and then I tried to install ksh via yaourt and aur

```
                                      ksh

              ---------------------------------------------------
                1) View/Edit PKGBUILD
              ---------------------------------------------------
              * b)  Build with makepkg and install with pacman.
                s)  Save build files and build.
                n)  Next package. Skip this package.
                q)  Quit without building.
              ---------------------------------------------------

              Enter a selection: [B] b
==> Checking Buildtime Dependencies... 

==> Checking Runtime Dependencies... 

==> Making package: ksh 2011.02.08-1 (Fri Jan 20 16:38:02 CST 2012)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving Sources...
==> ERROR: INIT.2011-02-08.tgz was not found in the build directory and is not a URL.
aurbuild: could not build ksh with makepkg.
Build directory retained at /var/tmp/aurbuild/build/ksh
You can visit the directory, fix the problem, and run makepkg.
```

[srikanth@myhost oracle]$ yaourt -S ksh

```
==> Downloading ksh PKGBUILD from AUR...
x PKGBUILD

( Unsupported package: Potentially dangerous ! )
==> Edit PKGBUILD ? [Y/n] ("A" to abort)
==> ------------------------------------
==> n

==> ksh dependencies:

==> ksh conflicts:
 - pdksh-5.2.14-6

==> Continue building ksh ? [Y/n]
==> -----------------------------
==> 
==> Building and installing package
==> Making package: ksh 2011.02.08-1 (Thu Jan 19 21:57:07 CST 2012)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving Sources...
==> ERROR: INIT.2011-02-08.tgz was not found in the build directory and is not a URL.
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build ksh.
==> Restart building ksh ? [y/N]
```

Please suggest.

I came across this [INIT package](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/download/).

Which package should I download for Arch Linux 64 bit?

Comment: Did you try [using the AUR package](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Oracle#Install_method_2_-_AUR)?

Comment: Oh, Thanks for suggestion. Infact, I did not do that. I will try it.

Comment: updated my answer for you on how to get ksh onto your system, hope it works :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As jasonwryan pointed out, you can do this more easily by using the [AUR package](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=23730). On the same wiki page that you provided, there is the [Install method 2 - AUR entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Oracle#Install_method_2_-_AUR), which explains how to install it through AUR. That approach should be easier and much more maintainable than doing it manually.

***edit:*** to install ksh, please take a look at its [PKGBUILD](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ks/ksh/PKGBUILD)

```
# AT&T requires the user to agree to a license agreement before downloading the
# source, so I didn't include the direct URLs in the PKGBUILD. Just visit
# 'http://www.research.att.com/~gsf/download/', download
# 'ast-ksh.2009-05-05.tgz' and 'INIT.2009-05-05.tgz', and place them in the
# same directory as the PKGBUILD before running makepkg
```

What you will have to do is:

1. go [here](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/) and download the needed packages
2. put them both in the some directory
3. navigate to that directory
4. create md5 hashes for that two packages with `md5sum filename`
5. execute yaourt -S ksh from the directory where the two packages are
6. when asked if you want to edit PKGBUILD say yes
7. edit *source* and *md5sums* lines (with new file names and new hashes)
8. save changes and exit editing
9. continue building ksh

If everything else is alright, ksh should install without problem.